# SCREENSHOT TOOL DOWNGRADED

Tags: screenshot

I have had Ubuntu for several years, beginning with bionic beaver, and since always installed the available updates.
I used to have a wonderful screenshot tool, it came within the utilities group. It allowed me to take full screen shots or pick an area and it allowed me to either save the screenshot to the clipboard or to browse to a folder on my system to save it to, and give it a filename.
Now since the most recent updates that tool has disappeared and in its place a more basic tool has turned up, called gnome screenshot. It doesn't allow me to name the file or choose a folder. In fact after I've taken a screenshot I cannot find it anywhere on my system.
Does anyone know how I can get the previous excellent screenshot tool back? Unfortunately I didn't observe a name.
I have searched in all the forums but nobody seems to know about this particular tool.

Comment: GNOME developers are known to not listen to the feedback of their users, and change working designs in favor of less efficient ones. If you want to use a more sophisticated tool, use deepin-screenshot https://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-install-deepin-screenshot-tool-on-ubuntu/ or shutter https://vitux.com/how-to-install-and-use-shutter-screenshot-tool-in-ubuntu/. You can configure them to open with the `print screen` button

Comment: Otherwise, you can also try MATE desktop or XFCE. There the default tools are more powerful.

Comment: "*[A]fter I've taken a screenshot I cannot find it anywhere on my system.*": Your Gnome screenshots are saved to `~/Pictures/Screenshots`. Take a look there. Each screenshot is also put into clipboard for easy immediate pasting. Having used many screenshot tools over the years, I consider the current tool to be well-designed, efficient to use, and easy to learn. Not a "downgrade" at all.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I have found Gnome developers to be responsive to bugs and constructive feedback that is in line with good design, and especially responsive when accompanied by a patch.

Comment: Thank you @ArchismanPanigrahi, very helpful, I will try these options.

Comment: Thank you @user535733 for your reply. I had already checked all possible folders such as /Pictures/Screenshots and /Downloads, the screenshots were nowhere to be found. I generally require to save screenshots as files and having them copied to the clipboard is not very useful (though this option was also available with the previous application). The previous application worked correctly and had more capabilities than the one replacing it, therefore the replacement meets the definition of a downgrade.

Comment: If you are saying that the Gnome screenshot tool in 22.04 and newer (not the older gnome-screenshot application) is not saving to `~/Pictures/Screenshots`, then that seems like a bug. Please test that functionality in a pre-release 23.10 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. If you can reproduce the problem, then please file a bug report so the Gnome developers can get that fixed. In my own testing, I could not reproduce the issue -- screenshots show up properly in that directory for me.